# Как убрать коллизию при повороте объекта в pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

У меня проблема, я поворачиваю все объекты вот так -

```
def rotate(image, angle):
rot_image = pygame.transform.rotate(image, angle) 
return rot_image
```

Но, у меня появляется либо обводка или коллизия спрайта.
Вот функция, обновляющая все процессы в мейн

def update_all():
pygame.display.flip()

```
rotatecards = 5
table = pygame.image.load('desk.png')
base.blit(table, (0, 0))
card1 = pygame.image.load(nitrogen.hand[0].image)
card2 = pygame.image.load(nitrogen.hand[1].image)
base.blit(rotate(card1, 0), (0, 600 - card.get_height()))
base.blit(rotate(card2, 0), (65, 600 - card.get_height()))

pygame.display.flip()
card3 = pygame.image.load(gustav.tablik.main[0].image)
card4 = pygame.image.load(gustav.tablik.main[1].image)
card5 = pygame.image.load(gustav.tablik.main[2].image)
if temp > 1:
    card6 = pygame.image.load(gustav.tablik.main[3].image)
    if temp > 2:
        card7 = pygame.image.load(gustav.tablik.main[4].image)
base.blit(rotate(card3, rotatecards), (250, 325 - card.get_height()))  # начальные карты стола
rotatecards -= 5
base.blit(rotate(card4, rotatecards), (300, 325 - card.get_height()))
rotatecards -= 5
base.blit(rotate(card5, rotatecards), (350, 325 - card.get_height()))
rotatecards -= 5
if temp > 1:
    base.blit(rotate(card6, rotatecards), (400, 325 - card.get_height()))
    rotatecards -= 5
    if temp > 2:
        base.blit(rotate(card7, rotatecards), (450, 325 - card.get_height()))
        rotatecards -= 5

pygame.display.flip()

base.blit(rotate(card, 180), (675, 129 - card.get_height()))  # карты противника
base.blit(rotate(card, 180), (740, 129 - card.get_height()))
printr(str(nitrogen.tokens), 170, 550, True)
pygame.display.flip()
# Обновляем
```

в коде конечно много недочётов, так как я делаю на скорую руку, а потом исправляю, но надеюсь, этого хватит

вот картинка для понимания:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Gingery, пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve], который демонстрирует проблему

Comment: добавил!!!!!!!!